# Prove that there is no integer a for which $a^2 - 3a - 19$ is divisible by 289

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that there is no integer a for which $a^2 - 3a - 19$ is divisible by 289.
Not got any clue. Please help.

Comment: HINT: Check divisibility by $17$

Comment: And how to check divisibility by 17 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assume that $a^2 -3a -19 = 289n$ for some integers $a$, and $n$.

Then: $a^2 - 3a -19 - 289n = 0$, taking "delta"

$$\Delta = b^2 - 4ac = (-3)^2 -4(1)(-19-289n) = 9 + 76 + 1156n = 85 + 1156n = 17(5 + 4\times17n)$$

must be a perfect square.

Thus $17(5 + 4 \times 17n)$ can be written as a product of squares of primes. Since $17$ is a prime itself, the factor $5 + 4 \times 17n = 17p^2 \times q^2 \times ...t^2$ with $p, q, ..., t$ are primes.

But this means $5 + 4 \times 17n = 0 \pmod{17}$ a contradiction since it is $5 \pmod{17}$.

Comment: great answer!!!

Comment: The expression that must be a perfect square is $17(5+4*17n)$, not $17(5+4*289n)$.  It doesn't affect the argument, though.

Answer (score 8):

$a^2-3a-19 = (a+7)^2-17(a+4)$. For $17^2$ to divide this, $17$ has to divide both $a+7$ and $a+4$, which is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by mercio

let us find $x,y$ such that $x-y=3,x+y=17\implies x=10,y=7$

$$a^2-3a-19=(a-10)(a+7)+51$$

As $51$ is divisible by $17,$ so must be $(a-10)(a+7)$ to make $17|(a^2-3a-19)$

Now $17|(a-10)\iff 17|(a+7)$ as $(a+7)-(a-10)=17$

So, $17^2|(a-10)(a+7),$ but $17^2\not|51$

**Generalization**:

Let us find integer $x,y$ such that

$\displaystyle x-y=-3$(the coefficient of $a$)

and $\displaystyle x+y=17c$ so that either both or none $(a+x),(a-y)$ will be divisible by $17$

$\implies 2x=17c-3\implies c$  must be odd $=2d+1$(say) for some integer $d$

$\implies x=17d+7$ and $y=x+3=17d+10$

Now, $\displaystyle (a+x)(a+y)=\{a+(17d+7)\}\{a-(17d+10)\}=a^2-3a-(17d+7)(17d+10)$

$\displaystyle\implies a^2-3a-19=\{a+(17d+7)\}\{a-(17d+10)\}+(17d+7)(17d+10)-19$

$\displaystyle\implies a^2-3a-19=\underbrace{\{a+(17d+7)\}\{a-(17d+10)\}}_{\text{terms with difference }=17}+17^2(d^2+d)+51$

Now the logic is exactly same as the one above

In the above method $d=0$

Comment: why have you taken x-y=3, x+y=17,how did you feel that it was necesary ?

Comment: @user2369284, observe the coefficient of $3$ and we need modulo $17$ first. So that both or none of $a-x,a+y$ be divisible by $17$. See this(http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9431/n2-3n-5-is-not-divisible-by-121)

Comment: @user2369284, please have a look into the edited version

Answer (score 2):

Doing algebra with number systems is often easier than trying to do algebra with divisibility. This is one of those cases.

What you are asked to show is the same thing as showing

$$ a^2 -3a - 19 \equiv 0 \bmod 289 $$

has no solutions. $289$ is odd so that we can divide by $2$ — in particular, that means we can solve quadratic equations in the usual way. You can go through the exercise of completing the square if you like, but the quadratic formula works too:

$$\begin{align}
 a &= \frac{3 + \sqrt{(-3)^2 - 4 \cdot (-19)}}{2} \mod{289 }
\\ &= \frac{3 + \sqrt{85}}{2} \mod{289}
\end{align}
$$

where each choice of square root gives a solution, and conversely, every solution comes from a choice of square root. (for general moduli, it is possible to have more than two square roots, although that can't happen for odd prime powers, such as this problem)

To compute square roots, it is usually best to work modulo the prime factors first, then lift to powers of primes, and finally use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to patch the solution together. Here, $289 = 17^2$, so we only have to do the first two steps.

So first, we need

$$ \sqrt{85} = \sqrt{0} = 0 \mod{17}$$

Thus, if $85$ has a square root modulo $289$, it must be a multiple of 17.

However,

$$ (17c)^2 = 289c^2 = 0 \mod{289} $$

therefore $85$ does not have a square root modulo $289$. Thus, there is no solution for $a$.

Answer (score 1):

As $289=17^2,$ let us check the divisibility by $17$

$$a^2-3a-19\equiv0\pmod{289}\implies a^2-3a-19\equiv0\pmod{17}$$

$$\iff a^2-3a\equiv19\equiv2\iff4a^2-12a\equiv8\pmod{17}\text{ as }(4,17)=1$$

$$\iff(2a-3)^2\equiv0$$

$$\iff 2a\equiv3\pmod{17}\equiv20\iff a\equiv10\text{ as }(2,17)=1$$

So, $a=17c+10$ where $c$ is some integer

$$a^2-3a-19=(17c+10)^2-3(17c+10)-19\equiv51\pmod{289}$$

Comment: Initially , have you taken the expression to be divisible by 17 ?

Comment: @user2369284, yes, I have solved for modulo $17$ as it is a factor of $289$

Comment: but how can you take so when it is not given ?

Comment: @user2369284, do you know, if $a$ divides $b$ and $b$ divides $c;a$ must divide $c$. Btw, you can check other answers

Comment: @user2369284: No, you don't have to start by solving modulo $17$. However, the arithmetic involved is sometimes simpler if you solve modulo 17, then lift the solution to modulo 289 (e.g. this is often done to calculate square roots). IMO, you shouldn't think about divisibility at all: you should be thinking about modular arithmetic. But if you insist, you know that something divisible by 289 must also be divisible by 17, so it's fair to start there.

Comment: @Hurkyl, please find my other answer