# Show there is no solution to this equation

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I have to show that $2x^4-20x+8$ cannot be divided by $16$ without remainder. The only thing comes to my mind is to write $16$ as $4^2$ which hasn't been of any help.

Could you give me some hints to prove this?

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586666/prove-that-there-is-no-integer-a-for-which-a2-3a-19-is-divisible-by-289

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$2(x^2+5x)-7=2(x+9)(x-4)+65$$

As $x+9-(x-4)=13$

If $13|(x+9)\iff13|(x-4)$

Now check

if $13\mid(x+9)$

and if $13\nmid(x+9)$

Comment: I have been trying to figure out the rest of the proof, but  didn't understand how knowing whether or not (x+9) is divisible by 13 would help?

Comment: @Maja, If $13$ divides $x+9, 13^2$ will divide $2(x+9)(x-4)\implies2(x+9)(x-4)+65\equiv65\pmod{169}$   Else $13\nmid(x+9)\implies13\nmid2(x+9)(x-4)\implies13\nmid2(x+9)(x-4)+65$

Answer (score 0):

$\triangle' = 5^2 - 2(-7-169k) = 39 + 138k = 13(3+ 26k) \to 3+26k = 13n^2 \to 13|3$, contradiction !