# Divisibility of a Polynomial

Tags: modular-arithmetic, divisibility, quadratics

**Prove that for all $n$, $121\mid n^2+3n+5$.**

I thought proving $n^2 +3n+5\pmod{121}\equiv 0$ had no solutions would be a good start, so I completed the square of $n^2+3n+5($, and arrived at $(n+62)^2 \pmod{121} \equiv 3718$. Replacing $n+62$ by $x$, I lastly arrived at $x^2 \equiv 88\pmod{121}$. Now, Im stuck. Any **hints** would be appreciated.

Comment: My mistake, I've edited it.

Comment: This is not clear at all.  $121$ does not divide all the values of that polynomial (obviously).

Comment: for $n=1$ we get $$1+3+5=9$$ $9$ is not divisible by $121$

Comment: Note the use of \mid and \pmod in MathJax in my edits. Do you know that in all of the places where $n^2$ appears, you wrote { n }^{ 2 } where n^2 would suffice?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know

Comment: See also : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586666/prove-that-there-is-no-integer-a-for-which-a2-3a-19-is-divisible-by-289

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to prove that $121\nmid(n^2+3n+5)$, that is, $121$ does *not* divide $n^2+3n+5$.

First of all ask yourself whether $n^2+3n+5$ is a multiple of $11$. The equation $n^2+3n+5\equiv0\pmod{11}$ can be rewritten
$$
n^2-8n+16=(n-4)^2\equiv0\pmod{11}
$$
which only holds for $n\equiv4\pmod{11}$.

Now we know that a possible solution of $n^2+3n+5\equiv0\pmod{121}$ should have $n=11k+4$, so
$$
n^2+3n+5=121k^2+88k+16+33k+12+5=121(k^2+k)+33
$$
which is never $\equiv0\pmod{121}$

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that you are in fact trying to show the exact opposite of what you state.  That is, for all $n\in \mathbb Z$ we have $$120\,\nmid \,n^2+3n+5$$

To see this:

First, we solve the problem $\pmod {11}$.  It is easy to see that $$n^2+3n+5\equiv 0\pmod {11}\implies n\equiv 4\pmod {11}$$

So, it suffices to consider only $n$ of the form $11k+4$.  Suppose we had a counterexample of that form.  Then we'd have $$(11k+4)^2+3(11k+4)+5\equiv 0 \pmod {121}$$  But it is easy to see that this would imply $$16+12+5\equiv 0\pmod {121}$$ which is false, hence we have a contradiction.  Thus no such $n$ exists.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it! No last digit raised to the second power produces a last digit of $8.$ Thus, there are no solutions to $x^2 \equiv 88\pmod{121}$!

Comment: This reasoning is false.  For instance, $x^2\equiv 18\pmod {121}$ has a solution, namely $x\equiv 13$.

Answer (score 0):

Just consider the case n=1, for which the polynomial is equal to 9. This is a sufficient counterexample.