# (n+7)(n-4)+33/121 is always a fraction

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

If ((n+7)(n-4)+33)/121=x than proof that x is always a fraction  . How can I proof this.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586666/prove-that-there-is-no-integer-a-for-which-a2-3a-19-is-divisible-by-289   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9431/n2-3n-5-is-not-divisible-by-121

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $\;121=11^2\,$ but $\;(n+7)(n-4)+33=n^2+3n+5=(n-4)^2+11(n-1)\,$ where $\,n-4\,$ and $\,n-1\,$ cannot both be multiples of $\,11\,$.

Comment: While I follow the logic of the proof, how did you go from $n2+3n+5$ to $(n−4)2+11(n−1)$?  Yes, they are equal, but the second doesn't immediately come to me when looking at the first.

Comment: @Aaron Idea was to isolate some factor of $\,11\,$, then trying a few small numbers found the above. It is not the only such form, same argument would apply to $\,n^2+3n+5 = (n + 7)^2 - 11 (n + 4)\,$ for example.