# Is $n^2+3n+6$ divisible by 25, where $n$ is a integer?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

If we want $n^2+3n+6$ to be divisible by $25$, it firstly has to be divisible by $5$.
So, let's take a look at couple of cases:
$n=5k: 25k^2+15k+6$. The remainder is $6$, so it's not divisible by $25$.

$n=5k+1: 25k^2+25k+10$. The remainder is $10$, so it is not divisible by $25$.

And so on for $n=5k+2, n=5k+3, n=5k+4.$

1. Is this a good way to do this?

The other way that came to my mind would be following:

Let's say that $n^2+3n+6$ is divisible by $25$: $$n^2+3n+6=25k$$
$$n^2+3n+(6-25k)=0$$ 
If we solve this equation, we get $$n_{1,2}=\frac{-3 \pm \sqrt{5} \sqrt{20k-3}}{2}.$$ But $\sqrt{5}$ is a irrational number, so is $n$ irrational number too. This is contradiction, so it's not divisible by $25$.

2. Is this a good way to solve this problem?

Comment: Your second method needs to consider $\sqrt{20k-3}$ too as that might balance the $\sqrt{5}$ and make the overall result rational - in fact it does not, but you have not shown it does not

Answer (score 2):

If $25$ divides  $n^2+3n+6,$ the later will be divisible by $5$

$n^2+3n+6\equiv n^2-2n+1\pmod5$

So, we need $n\equiv1\pmod5\implies n=1+5m$

$(5m+1)^2+3(5m+1)+6=25m^2+25m+10\not\equiv0\pmod{25}$

Comment: @Dietrich, extra dot

Answer (score 1):

Hint: We have
$$
n^2+3n+6=(n+4)^2 \bmod 5
$$

Now look at Bill's answer at this duplicate:

[$n^2 + 3n +5$ is not divisible by $121$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9431/n2-3n-5-is-not-divisible-by-121)